# Can I have two (isolated) YouTube channels on the same account?

Tags: youtube, google-account

If I start a second channel on my YouTube account, will there be any way people will know that my account is linked to two channels?

I want to create a second channel but the subject matter is completely different. I don't want my subscribers from channel#1 to know about channel#2.

Answer (score 1):

You can create channels simply on https://youtube.com/channel_switcher, and there is no public-facing indication that you own both channels.

This goes for all brand pages btw, brand page identities in general are completely separated from their owners/managers identity.